# Add parent DIV css properties to child DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have a parent DIV `wrap` and 3 main child DIVs.`inputQ`,`inputQL`,`inputQR`. I am using a background color for `wrap`, but this color is not showing up for `inputQL`, `inputQR`.Since inputQL, inputQR are inside wrap, I believe its background color should be added to child one as well.  I am a beginner in this area, can you please let me what is wrong here ? how can I add same background color for inputQL, inputQR ?

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anoopcr/hfmghkp0/

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="inputQ">
    <div class="InputQuest">Text Middle</div>
    <div><input id="amnttext" class="textbox"></input></div>
  </div>

  <div class="inputQL">
    <div class="InputQuest">Text Left</div>
    <div><input id="loandtext" class="textbox"></input></div>
  </div>

  <div class="inputQR">
    <div class="InputQuest">Text Right</div>
    <div><input id="emidtext" class="textbox"></input></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#eee;
}



.inputQ{width:60%;margin: auto; padding:10px;height:50px;margin-top:50px; }
.inputQL{width:45%;margin: auto; height:50px;margin-top:50px;float:left;}
.inputQR{width:45%;margin: auto; height:50px;margin-top:50px;float:right; }



.InputQuest
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin:auto;
}


.textbox
{
  float:left;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family: verdana;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:4px;
  border-top-right-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
  width:30%;
}
```

Comment: add   overflow: hidden; to .wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Also neede to cell .wrap { overflow: hidden; }
**try this**

```css
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.inputQ{width:60%;margin: auto; padding:10px;height:50px;margin-top:50px; }
.inputQL{width:45%;margin: auto; height:50px;margin-top:50px;float:left;}
.inputQR{width:45%;margin: auto; height:50px;margin-top:50px;float:right; }



.InputQuest
{
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size:18px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin:auto;
}


.textbox
{
  float:left;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family: verdana;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:4px;
  border-top-right-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
  width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="inputQ">
    <div class="InputQuest">Text Middle</div>
    <div><input id="amnttext" class="textbox"></input></div>
  </div>

  <div class="inputQL">
    <div class="InputQuest">Text Left</div>
    <div><input id="loandtext" class="textbox"></input></div>
  </div>

  <div class="inputQR">
    <div class="InputQuest">Text Right</div>
    <div><input id="emidtext" class="textbox"></input></div>
  </div>

</div>
```